# python variable name change

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a bit of question with python.

I have a piece of code

```
screen.blit(badninja1,(badninja1px ,badninja1py))
screen.blit(badninja2,(badninja2px ,badninja2py))
screen.blit(badninja3,(badninja3px ,badninja3py))
```

I know it repeats 3 time and I want to do some refactoring.

That is a piece of python code
what it does was draw badninja1 at location badninja1px and badninja1py etc.
bandninja1, badninja1px, badninja1py and other are variable names.

I wanted to put this code in a for loop

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    #add number 1, 2, 3 to the variable name.
```

I tried to do that and realized that I can combine string easily in python:

```
"Dec "+str(25)+"th".
```

However, changing variable name is a bit tricky.

Can anybody give ma a hint thanks!!

Comment: Messing with variable names is not a good practice (in any language): try a different approach to the problem

Comment: thanks! I had limited time to get a game working.
It was not the best practice, I know. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

You'd normally keep those values in lists or dictionaries instead:

```
badninjas = [badninja1, badninja2, badninja3]
```

and keep information like their location *with* the `badninja` objects:

```
for ninja in badninjas:
    screen.blit(ninja, (ninja.px, ninja.py))
```

You *can* look up variables dynamically, using either the `globals()` or `locals()` results (both return a mapping) but generally speaking you should avoid such behaviour. It certainly shouldn't be needed here.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to not use numbers in a variable name. Use a list instead:

```
badninja = [firstitem, seconditem, thirditem, ...]
```

Now you can pass `badninja[0]` to your function to specify the first item etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the variables explicitly, put them in the list then iterate over this one:

```
my_list = [(badninja1, badninja1px ,badninja1py),
           (badninja2, badninja2px ,badninja2py),
           (badninja3, badninja3px ,badninja3py)]
for item in my_list:
    screen.blit(item[0], (item[1], item[2]))
```